# .Net programming choosing the right platform

Tags: .net

I'm now converting an old classic asp intranet website to .Net.
I wave to decide between aspx, winforms, wpf, mvc.
I want quick development so I'm trying to run away from aspx, but if I have to I have to.

What do you guys suggest?

Thanks

Comment: Obviously ASP.NET and MVC are web technologies and winforms and WPF aren't (unless you mean Silverlight). Do you want to keep the application as a web app?

Comment: Just pick the one with the coolest set of letters. That's the best advice we can give you with no more information than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.Net is more similar to classic ASP then the other platforms, so going that route would probably be fastest and require the least departure from the original.  MVC is the latest fad, so that would probably be your best bet in terms of the potential lifespan of your rewrite.

If you're going to convert it to a Windows app, use WPF.  Winforms is pretty much deprecated, although that doesn't mean it's impossible to create good software with it.

Answer (score 1):

For an intranet site I would recommend you using some kind of CMS framework, otherwise you will reinvent the wheel more times than you can count: Free ones off the top of my head: 
- N2
- Umbraco

Personally I have a thing for EPiServer which sets you back some $10k usd or something, depending on the case it is well worth the money.

Having the intranet on a platform like winforms or WPF doesn't really make a lot of sense to me,

I'd go with aspx or mvc and a CMS system

Comment: If your wheel is square, you're pretty much forced to re-invent it. :)